# What is the behavior of EntryProcessor serialization?

Tags: hazelcast

I noticed that the EntryProcessor interface implements Serializable. I have a value in the map that I want to update using executeOnKey method, but would rather use the DataSerializable interface on the EntryProcessor for obvious reasons. My question... What is the behavior? Does the executeOnKey ignore the DataSerializable interface? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hazelcast send your `EntryProcessor` through `Operation` which implements the `DataSerializable` interface. The serialization of the instances of `EntryProcessor` are delegated to the `SerializationService`

So :

1. You can implement `DataSerializable` : Hazelcast will use it
2. You can register a custom Serializer for your implementation of `EntryProcessor`
3. If you do nothing, the java serialization will be used

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was extremely helpful.